# Unable to start service intent u=0 when trying to bind to service

Tags: android, aidl

We have two apps now, say app1 and app2. We want to start app2 first and then app2 will call context.bindService() to invoke app1 without even requiring app1 to be started first.
We are using the below code to bind the service

```
context.applicationContext.bindService(intent, ServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

In the Manifest we are giving the full service package name and also query packages in manifest like the other posts mentioned.
Now this flow has been working perfectly fine on almost all the devices. But only on one device we checked the logcat and it's reporting

```
unable to start service intent {cmp...} u=0
```

But the strange thing is on this device, if we start app1 first and then start app2, it is able to bind. If app1 is not started, then we see the error.
Has anyone ever seen this issue before or have any ideas?
Any help will be much appericated!